# How can I use the CalendarExtender component in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, calendar, visual-studio-2015, calendarextender

I work with Visual Studio 2015 and I need to use the CalendarExtender component from the toolbox but I can't because the only available component is Calendar. Should I download it from somewhere?

Please help me

Comment: Did you check  the nuget package gallery?